# Returning a nested JSON object to front end as text in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm successfully fetching from an API but having trouble rendering the data I want to the front end in React.

I'm trying to return the entire contents of the 'model' object within Article component which is a set of key/value pairs. The ArticleList component maps the `body` key representing an array and the `type` and `model` are passed as props to the Article component.

The JSON of the mock API being accessed is here for reference of the structure: https://www.mocky.io/v2/5c6574b33300009010b99de4

I can't use map on the inner objects because they are not arrays. The `console.log` in my code is correctly returning the contents of the model object for each entry in the array within the inspection window. However, I can't get it to display in the browser view.

In the Article component the use of `Object.toString(model)` is temporary code I added in to allow my browser window to render and it displays the following in the browser view:

```
Object: function Object() { [native code] }
```

So, to be clear my app is returning the full model object to the browser and not the contents within as desired.

ArticleList component is:

```
import Article from './Article';

const ArticleList = ({article}) => {

    const articleNodes =  article.body.map((section)=>{

        return (
            <>
            <Article type={section.type} model={section.model} />    
            </>
            
        )
    })
    return (
        <>
            {articleNodes}          
        </>
    );

}

export default ArticleList;
```

Article component which is receiving the props of type and model is:

```
function Article({type, model}) {

    console.log(model);

    if (!type) return null;

    return(
        <>
      <h1>type: {type}</h1>
      <h1>Object: {Object.toString(model)}</h1>     
        </>
    );

}

export default Article;
```

Please advise? I believe the fix could be simple within my `<h1>` tag of Article component but I have tried to no avail.

Edit: I want to be able to semantically tag each key value pair to render the images within the "url" key within img tags etc. Therefore I ideally need to have the ability to return individual JSX elements representing the properties in the object such as I have done with the map in ArticleList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A component for every type

You'll need to create multiple components for each `type` of data you're receiving. That means a component for the `heading` type, for the `paragraph` type, etc.

```
const Paragraph = ({ text }) => (
  <p>{text}</p>
);

export default Paragraph
```

### Finding the right component for the right type.

Now that you've created multiple components for each `type` your API returns, you'll need to find a way to *select* the component that corresponds with the current `type` value.

An easy way to do this is to create a *map* object. The keys will represent the possible types and the values a function that return the component.

```
const typesMap = {
  'paragraph': (props) => <Paragraph {...props}/>
}
```

The example above shows a single option called `paragraph`. (Other types `heading`, `image`, etc. are yours to add.) The value is a function with a single parameter called `props`. The function returns a Paragraph component and passes all available props to the component with the [`...` spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

The spread syntax allows us not to hardcode our props like the example below,

```js
<Paragraph text={text} someprop={somevalue} />
```

but passes all the properties and values in the `props` object to the component, saving us effort and time.

### Selecting the component

We have an object of keys that represent types and values that represent the components. All you have to do now is to select the component based on the `type` value. And we can do that like this:

```
const TypeComponent = typesMap[type];
```

Remember, the selected value is a function that returns a component, like `<Paragraph/>`. Which would be the same as something like this:

```
const ExampleComponent = ({ props }) => (
  <Paragraph {...props}/>
);
```

In React (functional) components are nothing more than actual `function`s that return values. That's why we can write `TypeComponent` like a component and call it like this:

```
<TypeComponent {...props} />
```

The name `TypeComponent` can be anything you'd like. I thought that it was appropriate for the context it is in.

Now all you have to do is pass the `model` object to the dynamically created `TypeComponent` with the spread syntax, saving you the trouble of writing all the props and values for each type.

```
import Paragraph from './Paragraph';

const typesMap = {
  'paragraph': props => <Paragraph {...props} />,
//'heading': props => ...
//'image': ... 
};

function Article({ type, model }) {
  if (!type) return null;

  const TypeComponent = typesMap[type];

  return <TypeComponent {...model} />;
}

export default Article;
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution does return the model object data to the window. However, I want to be able to semantically tag each key value pair to, for example, render the images within the "url" key within img tags etc. Therefore I ideally need to have the ability to return individual JSX elements, like I have done with the "type" <h1> tag. Would you be able to kindly amend your solution to facilitate more control over the data stored within the model objects?

Comment: I've modified the answer. Could you take another look?

Comment: That worked. Awesome. Thank you. I have accepted your solution. If you wouldn't mind - could you perhaps explain further. Does the method above merge the model key/value pairs into the model key by means of a map? I am not fully comprehending what the code is doing so would appreciate any further explanation you can provide (the more verbose, the better). I'm new to React and have also never seen local component creation i.e definition AND usage (TypeComponent) via fragments locally within another component. Normally work with separate js files.

Comment: You're welcome. I've done my best to add more details to help you out. If you have any more questions, please let me know.